# How to configure Jenkins for 2FA enabled github account?

Tags: node.js, github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops

My account has 2FA enabled and my repo is private. I'm trying to deploy my node.js application using Jenkins to AWS Ec2 and everything works fine including (build, tests, coverage) but in the end deploy does not work because of 2FA issue. I have added my username and token in jenkins which seems to work but as soon as I run git commands like `git pull` which asks for username and password on runtime, because of that Jenkins could not connect to github and can't pull any changes.
Here is the stage for deploy:

```
stage('deploy') {
              steps {
                  withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'someid', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')]){
                    echo 'Deploying to aws ec2'
                    sh '''#!/bin/bash
                    ssh ubuntu@ip-555.55.55.5 <<EOF
                     cd /var/www/app
                     sudo git reset --hard HEAD # problem is likely to be here because it requires username and password
                     sudo git pull
                     npm install
                     pm2 restart all
                     exit
                    EOF
                    '''
                  }

          }
```

Comment: I thought GitHub removed [username/password option](https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/); must be username/PAT.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by adding a ssh key and changing remote url to Github ssh url.